# Error (E_VALIDATION) :: 1 attribute is invalid

Tags: node.js, waterline, oriento, sails-orientdb

I'm trying to update one line using sails-orientdb, this way:

```
      CommentModel.update({
        _id: req.body.reply.commentId
      }, comment).exec(function (err, reply) {
        // *** LOG: LOOK BELOW
        console.log(comment, req.body.reply.commentId, reply);
        // ***
        if (err)
          return next(err);
        UserModel.findOne({
          id: reply.author
        }).exec(function (err, user) {
          reply.author = user.toJSON();
          res.json({
            success: !err,
            reply: reply
          });
        });
      });
```

> comment: { author: '#16:0',   node: '#30:13',   _id: '0dcb0fb8-35e9-4117-87e9-33e2ac21e0e0',   body: 'lkjnn',   replies: '[object Object]',   createdAt: '2015-07-21T08:50:52.000Z',   updatedAt: '2015-07-21T08:50:52.000Z',   id: null }
>
> req.body.reply.commentId: 0dcb0fb8-35e9-4117-87e9-33e2ac21e0e0
>
> reply: undefined

But, I'm getting this error message:

> Error (E_VALIDATION) :: 1 attribute is invalid

How to fix this, please? What's wrong?

Comment: It seems that your update is breaking one validation rule ([waterline docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models/validations.md)). Can you share your model definition?